# How do I get refreshToken after implicit grant flow

Tags: openid, aws-api-gateway

Implicit grant flow from amazon API responses only Access_token with OpenID. How can I get refresh_token later with an Implicit grant? Is there any way to access refresh_token with Access_token?

Answer (score 1):

In the Amazon API Gateway, the Implicit grant flow only returns an access token when the user logs in. The refresh token is not returned as part of this flow, because the Implicit grant flow is designed for browser-based or mobile applications that need to access user information in the Amazon Cognito user pool.

If you need to refresh the access token after it has expired, you can use the Authorization Code grant flow instead of the Implicit grant flow. This flow returns both an access token and a refresh token when the user logs in. You can then use the refresh token to get a new access token when the original access token expires.

To use the Authorization Code grant flow, you will need to configure the Amazon Cognito user pool to support this flow and modify your application to use the authorization code to get the access and refresh tokens. You can find more information about the Authorization Code grant flow in the Amazon Cognito Developer Guide.

In summary, it is not possible to get a refresh token using the Implicit grant flow in Amazon API Gateway. If you need to refresh the access token, you will need to use the Authorization Code grant flow instead.

Answer (score 0):

Implicit grant is considered deprecated and insecure. refresh_token is not part of the OAuth2 spec for the implicit flow as it's a little pointless. If you *could* refresh, you can also use the `auhtorization_code` flow; which is what you really *should do* anyway.

implicit flow exists from a time where browsers couldn't as easily do javascript-driven HTTP requests, but this is a long time ago.